# Sorting a queue - C/C++

Tags: c++, sorting, queue

I have created a queue that in each node there are three information. I want to create a member function in class that sorts the queue when called. I wish to have the queue sorted by time? (it is an int and a member of q_node). This queue needs to be sorted in such a way that the lowest value of 'time' is in the front and it is sorted in increasing order.
My code for my Queue is found below:

```
typedef struct Qnode{
    int time;
    char name[10];
    char value;

    struct Qnode *q_next;
    struct Qnode *q_prev;
} q_node;

class Queue{
private:
    q_node *q_rear;
    q_node *q_front;
    int number;
public:
    Queue();
    void enqueue(int time, char *s, char value);
    q_node *q_top(){
        return q_front;
    }
    void dequeue();
    void display();
    void queueSort();
    bool isEmpty();
};

Queue::Queue(){
    q_rear = NULL;
    q_front = NULL;
    number = 0;
}

bool Queue::isEmpty(){
    if (q_front == NULL)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

void Queue::enqueue(int t, char *n, char v){
    q_node *q_temp = new q_node;

    q_temp->time = t;
    strcpy(q_temp->name , n);
    q_temp->value = v;
    q_temp->q_next = NULL;

    if(q_front == NULL){
        q_front = q_temp;
    }
    else{
        q_rear->q_next = q_temp;
    }
    q_rear = q_temp;
    number++;
}

void Queue::dequeue(){
    q_node *q_temp = new q_node;
    q_temp = q_front;
    q_front = q_front -> q_next;
    number--;
    delete q_temp;
}


void Queue::display(){
    q_node *p = new q_node;
    p = q_front;
    while(p!=NULL){
        cout<< "\ntime: " << p->time;
        cout<< "\nname: " << p->name;
        cout<< "\nvalue: " << p->value;
        cout << endl;
        p = p->q_next;
    }
}

void Queue::queueSort(){
    //Code for sorting

}
```

Comment: Please pick *one* programming language language.

Comment: @juanchopanza code is clearly c++.

Comment: @saadtaame That is debatable. It looks like C written with some C++ featurews. But so what? The question mentions two languages and has two tags.

Comment: Do you want the queue to *always* be sorted? Then just insert at the right position when inserting a node.

Comment: a simple bubble-sort should do if it is a small queue. check out the bubble-sort algorithm by using xx (insert your favorite search engine) instead of expecting us to do the code for you.

Comment: By the way, since you're programming in C++ you should really use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead of pointers and arrays. You have a big problem if the user of your code tries to add a node with a string longer than nine characters.

Comment: I think need to take a second look at your dequeue function. The code          
       `q_node *q_temp = new q_node;`        `q_temp = q_front;`     seems to give memory leaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to dump the queue into an array or vector by using `dequeue`, use `std::sort` and then rebuild the queue from scratch by using your `enqueue` function. This is clean and avoids messing up with pointers. This is also optimal because running time is dominated by time it takes to sort.

Something like:

```
v = vector of nodes
while(Q.isEmpty() == false)
{   v.push_back(*Q.top());
    Q.dequeue();
}

sort(v.begin(), v.end(), cmp);

for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
{   Q.enqueue(v[i].time, v[i].name, v[i].value);
}
```

Where `cmp` compares nodes by time.

Answer (score 0):

Find the node with the smallest `time` field, remove it from the list and make it the head of a new list. Then continue to do this, appending the nodes to the new list, in a loop while the original list is not empty. When the original list is empty, take the new (sorted) list and make it the new queue.

It might not be especially efficient, but should work fine.